# Redefinging global for a module in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, require, commonjs, ice

I have a node module ([IceJS](http://www.zeroc.com/labs/icejs/index.html)) which insists on putting all of its exports, not in `module.exports`, but in `global`. In there a way to sandbox the module and take its `global.ice` and return it as a normal node module, as in `var ice = require("Ice");`?

Comment: are you asking how to modify the ice source to accomplish this?

Comment: No, I want to change where Ice puts itself, without modifying its source because that is nigh on impossible, as it has many files, all required in, modifying `global`, and not using CommonJS.

Comment: If ice isn't causing problems besides being in global you could just create a wrapper which requires it, then assigns the module.exports = global.iceproperty

Comment: A wrapper such as `require("Ice"); module.exports = global.ice;` keeps ice in global, even in the file requiring the wrapper.

Comment: looks like it is designed to work in browser (hence puts itself in a global object), so even if you managed to wrap it in a CommonJS module, it wouldn't work anyway

Comment: that has been fixed in latest release, Ice module are not longer global in NodeJS, https://www.npmjs.com/package/zeroc-icejs